# SQLite doesn't create rows and crashes

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add an object from class Product to my SQLite database, but if I call dbhandler.addProduct(Product product) method the emulator crahes and logcat doesn't show any error.

My ListviewActivity :

```
     ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter;
ArrayList<Product> productnames=new ArrayList<>();
DBHandler dbhandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView productList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    dbhandler=new DBHandler(this,null,null,1);

    adapter= new CustomAdapter(this,productnames);
    productList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
public void addNewProduct(View view){
    EditText userInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
    userInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String productname=userInput.getText().toString();

    if(productname.equals(""))return;

    Product product=new Product();
    product.set_productname(productname);
    product.set_checked(false);
    productnames.add(product);
    dbhandler.addProduct(product);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    userInput.setText("");

}
```

if i comment out dbhandler.addProduct(product) everything works fine.

my DBHandler class:

```
public class DBHandler  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="products.db";
    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS= "products";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID="_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME="productname";
    public static final String COLUMN_ISCHECKED="ischecked";

    public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query= "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "("+
                COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "TEXT" +
                COLUMN_ISCHECKED + "BOOLEAN" +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_PRODUCTS );
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public  void addProduct(Product product){
        ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME,product.get_productname());
        values.put(COLUMN_ISCHECKED,product.is_checked());
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS,null,values);
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: What crashes?? Are you getting?

Comment: first check in /data/data/packagename/databases/products.db exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add **SPACES** between the column names and the column types:

```
   String query= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " ("+
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_ISCHECKED + " BOOLEAN" +
            ")";
```

And the columns must be **comma separated**.

Same goes for the table name (missing a space)